# What is an association between two tables?

Tags: mysql, relationship

An association between two tables, such as the order headers and order details tables, is called a relationship, not schema correct?

Comment: You could've searched this on Google.

Comment: if you desire you can call it "marriage" as well, you can name it anything you want, or if you are looking for standard names, then google it or read Textbooks. to answer your question. Yes it part of complete schema and it can be define as relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "database schema" is composed of all of the table and column definitions and the constraints therein.  Arguably the schema also includes all database objects such as views and indexes.  To write a query, you must know the database schema.  To write a correct query, you must know the schema and its relationships.

A relationship pertains to how tables are joined together.  For example, employees to departments will typically have a many-to-one relationship if an employee can only work in one department.  If an employee can be split between departments, the relationship is many to many.

To wit, a **relation** (without the -ship) is something totally different.  A relation is the set of tuples (rows) that results from the application of a constraint (as defined by a relationship) to the the cross product of said tables.  It is from this word that we get the term "relational database."

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is often refereed to as a Foreign Key relationship.

When referencing the relationship within a query it is called a Join.

There are a few types of joins

inner joins - includes only matching records based on the key relationship
outer joins - includes matching and unmatching records based on the key relationship, this join can be left outer join or right outer join.

A schema defines the structure of the database, including tables, views, stored procedures, constraints, indexes and security objects.  A database can contain multiple schemas defined within it.